# Edit text after dot with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

I want to remove three digits after dot in last 3 columns with batch file (windows). Note that dots can be present in other columns.

This is a sample of my data:

```
4216118,'0806010709','ljubičasti ','Hita kirška ambnta',1,'Eriiti (vk, kk)','X','Uđaj za heološke prege','Celyn1800 ','Hni Sak','Hemlogja','2016-06-08 11:42:05.040','2016-06-08 11:41:42.122','2016-06-08 11:49:49.370'
4216081,'0806010387','ljubičasti ','Oća doven.amb. - VANJA',1,'Erii (vk, kk)',,'Urj za heoške prage','Adia 120 R','Reni','Hlogija','2016-06-08 08:52:13.962','2016-06-08 08:51:57.067','2016-06-08 11:08:26.504'
4216667,'1506010909','ljčasti ','tna ambuta kke za invne bolesti',1,'Erciti (vk, kk)',,'Uj za hemloške prge','Cell-Dyn 1800 R','Hi','Hemagija','2016-06-15 21:24:14.646','2016-06-15 21:24:03.523','2016-06-15 21:26:58.871'
4213710,'0905010991','ljubičasti ','Hna kira amnta',1,'Eociti (vk, kk)','X','Uđaj za hemloške prage','Cel1800 ','Hi Sak','Hemlogja','2016-05-09 17:52:32.231','2016-05-09 17:52:26.319','2016-05-09 18:31:33.643'
```

Example:
Before:

```
'2016-06-08 11:49:49.370'
```

After:

```
'2016-06-08 11:49:49'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47642335.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('more %filename1%') DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 ECHO !line:~0,-57!!line:~-53,-31!!line:~-27,-5!!line:~-1!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q47642335.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Sadly, `cmd` doesn't play nicely with unicode files, so there will be some modification to the data. Essentially, read each line and pick the line-portions to be concatenated, using `-` substringing values to select from the end of the line, which is of a consistent structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, without any guaranties. Regarding your example, expect you want remove last three digits AND dot, unlike your describe to remove three digits AFTER dot.

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION > out.txt
for /f "tokens=1-15 delims=," %%a in (data.txt) do (
            set "string="
            call :process "%%a" "%%b" "%%c" "%%d" "%%e" "%%f" "%%g" "%%h" "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l" "%%m" "%%n" "%%o"
            )
exit /B

:process
echo %~1| findstr /R /C:"[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]" >NUL
if not errorlevel 1 (
            set "str=%~1"
            set "str=!str:~0,-5!"
            if defined string (set "string=!string!,!str!'") else (set "string='!str!'")
            ) else (
            set "str=%~1"
            if defined string (set "string=!string!,!str!") else (set "string='!str!'")
            )
shift           
if not "%~1"=="" (goto :process) else (echo !string!>>out.txt)
GOTO:EOF
```